# Updating a Canvas after a Button click?

Tags: java, swing, canvas

I am testing using graphics for a TicTacToe game but I am having a problem updating the Canvas after a button click. When I call **showUpdatedBoard()**, it creates a new Canvas from the **Canvas** class but it does not enter the **paintComponent** method, therefore not updating the Canvas.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

(Ignore the count and i, they were just for testing)

TicTacToe Class:

```
public class TicTacToe extends JPanel{

private JFrame mainFrame;
private JPanel mainPanel;
private JPanel canvasPanel;
private JPanel optionsPanel;
private JTextField coord;
private JButton enterCoord;

private int i = 0;

public static void main(String[] args){

    TicTacToe tictac = new TicTacToe();
    tictac.mainFrame = new JFrame();
    tictac.mainFrame.setSize(1600, 900);
    tictac.mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    tictac.mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(tictac.mainFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    tictac.mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    tictac.makeGUI();

}

public void showUpdatedBoard(){
    canvasPanel = new Canvas();
    canvasPanel.repaint();
}

private void makeGUI(){

    canvasPanel = new Canvas();

    mainPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    mainPanel.add(canvasPanel);

    mainFrame.add(mainPanel);

    optionsPanel = new JPanel();
    coord = new JTextField(4); 

    enterCoord = new JButton("Enter Co-ordinate");
    enterCoord.addActionListener(new enterCoordPress());

    optionsPanel.add(coord);
    optionsPanel.add(enterCoord);

    mainPanel.add(optionsPanel);
}

public class enterCoordPress implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
        TicTacToe tictac = new TicTacToe();
        tictac.showUpdatedBoard();
        i++;
        coord.setText(String.valueOf(i));
    }
}
}
```

Canvas Class:

```
public class Canvas extends JPanel {

private String[][] Board = new String[3][3];
private int count = 0;

public Canvas(){
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1300, 900));
    this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    System.out.println(count);
    if(count <= 5){
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 1000, 900);
    } else {
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 120, 546);
    }
    count++;
}

}
```

Comment: See [*Mixing Heavyweight and Lightweight Components*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/mixing-components-433992.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
canvasPanel.update(canvasPanel.getGraphics());
```

instead of

```
canvasPanel.repaint();
```

Comment: Unless you are printing or generating a snap shot of the component, there should never be cause to call update (or any) paint method directly, especially not using `getGraphics` which can return null, especially when that method can return null when the component hasn't be realised yet

Comment: I get a NullPointerException?

Comment: @Latrinum `getGraphics` returns `null` when the component hasn't been attached to a native peer, you should never rely on it

Answer (score 0):

Basically, when you use `new` you are creating a brand new instance of the component, one which has no relationship anything you've created before and one which does not appear on the screen, doing...

```
canvasPanel = new Canvas();
canvasPanel.repaint();
```

Is do nothing because Swing is smart enough to know that your component hasn't been realised (attached to a native peer and put on the screen), so it never schedules it for any painting, it would a waste of time to do so.

Instead, you need to update the state of `canvasPanel` in some way to reflect the changes you want to appear and simply call `repaint`

The same goes for your `actionPerformed` method, don't create a new instance of `TicTacToe` as it's not the instance of the component that's actually on the screen...

Comment: Where would I be able to edit the Canvas outside of paintComponent()?

Comment: You already have a reference `canvasPanel` in `TicTacToe`. You're `ActionListener`, `enterCoordPress`, should be able to reference it directly.  All you need then is some way for the `ActionListener` to change the state of the `canvasPanel`, either via a common model (which would be preferred) or directly via some kind setter

Comment: I fixed it by calling repaint() in a new method in the Canvas class and then I called repaint() in TicTacToe. Thanks for the help!